# Laravel 5 WhereIn Not Working

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have no idea why my query is suddenly not working (although maybe it was never working to begin with). Is there anything wrong here?

My controller;

```
$dataset = $postcode_lookup->dataset; // will return "201502_postcode"  

$postcode_extract = new PostcodeExtract;
$postcode_extract = $postcode_extract->setTableByDate($dataset);

foreach ($input as $column => $values) {
    $postcode_extract->orWhere(function ($query) use ($column, $values) {
                            $query->whereIn($column, $values);
                        });
}

/*
*  Temporarily print out the raw SQL...
*/
$sql = str_replace(['%', '?'], ['%%', "'%s'"], $postcode_extract->toSql());
$fullSql = vsprintf($sql, $postcode_extract->getBindings());
print_r($fullSql);

exit;
```

My model;

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PostcodeExtract extends Model {

protected $connection = 'postcodes';

public function setTableByDate($selected_tablename)
{
    $this->table = $selected_tablename;

    // Return $this for method chaining
    return $this;
}

public function getTable()
{
    if (isset($this->table))
        $this->setTableByDate($this->table);

    return $this->table;
}
```

All that the print out of the raw sql is returning is `select * from 201502_postcode` and is just ignoring the rest of the query.

This is my `$input` array;

```
Array
(
[country] => Array
    (
        [0] => L93000001
        [1] => M83000003
    )

[county] => Array
    (
        [0] => 95
    )
)
```

orWhere and whereIn is just being ignored it seems..

--- UPDATE ---

I didn't know about orWhereIn. But having tried this;

```
foreach ($input as $column => $values) {
        $postcode_extract->orWhereIn($column, $values);

        print "<br>";
        print $column;
        print "<br>";
        print_r($values);
        print "<br>";
}
```

I still get the same result. It's like this loop is being totally ignored - even though I can get these print's/print_r's to work. The raw SQL is still just `select * from 201502_postcode`.

Comment: I don't see the need for a nested where here. Maybe try just `orWhereIn()`? Also please verify that the loop really works. (e.g. with `echo`)

Comment: you should wrap your `foreach` in a `where(function ...)` and inside the closure use simply `orWhereIn`.

Comment: @lukasgeiter See update. It is going through the loop at least.. But still producing the same result. I'm so confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh this is so frustratingly obvious I think I might cry...

```
foreach ($input as $column => $values) {
        $postcode_extract = $postcode_extract->orWhereIn($column, $values);     
}
```

Comment: @lukasgeiter - do you know why?? I'm so confused by it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$postcode_extract->orWhereIn($column, $values)
```

Also, if that doesnt work, try making the first one condition a `whereIn` and the rest a `orWhereIn`

Comment: I didn't know about orWhereIn.. but even that still produces the same result. That whole loop is just being ignored. See update on original post